# Configure Opera to permanenty use pac proxy config

Tags: proxy, linux-mint, opera

Is there a way to configure Opera to use `.pac` file proxy config?

When I click "Change Proxy Settings" in Settings there is only info how to achieve it via command line params:

```
--proxy-pac-url=URL
Set up a proxy server using autoconfiguration. The URL should point to a proxy autoconfiguration URL.
```

I don't want to enter this param every time I start browser. There must be  better solution (maybe some config file?) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should update `opera.desktop` file:

- system-wide: /usr/share/applications/opera.desktop
- per-user: ~/.local/share/applications/opera.desktop

Find and update line starting from `Exec=`

from `Exec=opera %U` to `Exec=opera --proxy-pac-url=file:///path/to/pac-file %U`

More info about desktop file you can find on the following page: [Desktop Entry Specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec/)